# Run init script when Docker with MySQL is ready

Tags: scripts, mysql, 20.04, docker

I am trying to run a script for initialization of MySQL within a Docker container. I just want to run it once, as it creates the default user for MySQL.

/root/mysql-init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root < /root/mysql-user-setup.sql
```

/root/mysql-user-setup.sql:

```
USE mysql;
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I tried to run the script as a Docker `ENTRYPOINT`, but it fails. Docker command inside the `dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/mysql-init.sh"]
```

Error when starting the Docker container:

```
2020-05-21T00:51:36.741895785Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

So I assume that I try to execute the script during a time where the MySQL service has not yet been started. Hence, the script fails. I would therefore have two possible solutions:

1. Repeatedly check if the MySQL service exists from inside the script.
2. Start the script in a different way as with `ENTRYPOINT`.

Is that the right approach?

Comment: They are many mysql/ariadb  docker image , can specify which are you using ?